# Are there any monsters in D&D lore that focus on devouring memories?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore

Are there any monsters in D&D that would feed on memories/emotions?

I know about illithid and intellect devourers, but I was hoping there might be another type of monster that is known for that stuff. I'm working on an NPC backstory, so the edition of the monster doesn't matter; it's just for backstory purposes. (I don't actually need stats or anything.)

Any information would be a great help!

Comment: I get that the monster needs to feed on memories - is it important whether this removes the host's access to those memories?  Is it important whether this is the only thing the monster feeds on?

Comment: Can this be turned into a community wiki? There are several answers below which are all "right", and it would be better to collect them into one answer.

Answer (score 18):

### Oblex

The [Oblex](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Oblex) is able to eat the memories of a creature and then impersonate them. Oblexes are highly intelligent oozes created by the mind flayers. They eat memories as a means of gaining sustenance and can use the memories and abilities they gain to hunt other prey.

Answer (score 10):

**Shadow Demon** (MM, p. 54)

> A shadow demon uses its insubstantial claws to **feast on
> its victim's fears, to taste its memories**, and drink in
> its doubts.

**Flumph** (MM, p. 135)

This one is unusual in not being evil, for a change.

> Flumphs feed by **siphoning mental energy** from psionic creatures, and they can be found lurking near communities of mind flayers, aboleths, githyanki, and githzerai. As passive parasites, they take only the mental energy they need, and most creatures feel no loss or discomfort from such feeding. Consuming psionic energy **reveals the thoughts and emotions of the creatures on which the flumphs feed**.

**Hydroloth** (*Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Universe*, p. 158)

> Like the thought-stealing waters of the River Styx they inhabit, hydroloths **filch the memories of creatures they attack**, stealing away thoughts for delivery to whatever master they happen to serve.

Comment: I'll add that historically some rare Aboleths also have the capability to devour the thoughts of mortals they eat. 3.5's Lords of Madness the most details on the subject.

Answer (score 7):

## False Hydra

This is not a perfect fit because it's not canonical to any D&D setting, but you said you are open to any editions, so maybe something from homebrew and D&D-adjacent folklore might also interest you:
https://goblinpunch.blogspot.com/2014/09/false-hydra.html

Comment: Note that the False Hydra, while not being official D&D content, is now a pretty famous meme within the D&D community.

Answer (score 3):

### Obliviax, also known as Oblivion Moss or Memory Moss

While it has not yet been printed in any 5th Edition book I'm familiar with, every prior edition has had stats for some version of Obliviax.

In broad strokes, a patch of obliviax can steal memories and even memorized spells, and eating from that same patch can give the eater the stolen memories (and spells, temporarily), though the moss is mildly poisonous.

Different editions have varied about how much obliviax is a plant creature versus a simple natural hazard, as well as how far into the past the memory theft could reach. In 1e it was just a hazard you might stumble into, like green slime or poison ivy, but later editions have granted it the ability to grow an ambulatory moss simulacrum of a person whose memories have been stolen.

Answer (score 2):

### The Hyakume

A many-eyed aberration that hungers for and steals memories seems appropriate, though I could only find a [3rd party definition](https://www.5esrd.com/database/creature/hyakume/) for them in 5e.

Otherwise they're also a creature from [Japanese folklore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legendary_creatures_(H)) if you're interested in the lore around them.

Answer (score 1):

## Feyr (Boo's Astral Managerie p. 22)

These [tentacled aberrations](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Feyr) feed on strong emotions, preferring to devour the nightmares of sleeping creatures to minimize the risk to themselves. Smaller feyrs are able to combine to form larger ones. They're typically found in large cities, where strong emotions are more plentiful.

Comment: I'd argue that emotions and memories are not the same thing, but a homebrew variation of this creature could work for this question.

Comment: I think this monster was originally based on a sci-fi flick, [Forbidden Planet](https://www.filmsite.org/forbiddenplanet.html)

Comment: @Matthieu The OP mentioned "memories/emotions," so I figured it'd be worth including in the list.